# How to recover a sublime 3 session?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Well, I'm using sublime text 3 and i did something really stupid. I just rewrote a file in which I've recently made some changes and lost it all. I did that pasting an older version, saving it and closing the file.

I need to know if there's any way to recover that old file. In my ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/ I can see two sublime_session files:

'Session.sublime_session' from yesterday and

'Auto Save Session.sublime_session' saved today

I have opened them with sublime, but how could I restore a file? Is it possible?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have any Time Machine backups?

Comment: @ILikeTau no I don't. :(

Comment: I don't thing sublime_session files store any file info; just the windows geometry and such.

Comment: Look through those two files and see if the old content is there. Sublime has a great search feature. If it's not there, use **a different text editor** to open your project's `.sublime-workspace` file. If nothing's there, tough. Learn a lesson and use version control next time.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo. Couldn't find this .sublime-workspace file, but I'll definitely learn this lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover changes in file closed with Sublime Text 3. When you close file, your undo buffer is lost forever.

Sublime Text 4 behave same way.